# Where Clause on same column twice with different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Table1: Agent Data: where agent details are stored
Agent Table

```
Agent_Id    Name
1   Vijay
2   Rajesh
3   Satish
4    Anji
```

Table2: Case_transaction_details: Each step in Backend operation is stored.
Case_transaction_details

```
Case_Id Stage   Login_Time  Logout_time Agent_id    Status
101 Maker   5/11/2019 10:20 10:30   2   Success
102 Maker   10:25   10:35   1   Success
103 Maker   10:40   10:50   2   Success
101 Checker 10:45   11:00   3   Success
101 Approver    11:15   11:30   2   Success
102 Checker 10:50   11:00   1   Reject
102 Maker   11:15   11:45   4   Reverify
103 Checker 11:30   11:40   2   Reject
```

The question is how to get Case Id which is  rejected by checker but still not reverified?

```
SELECT Case_Id 
FROM Case_transaction_detail  
WHERE Status = 'Reject' and status != 'Reverify';
```

How to apply where clause twice on same column?

trying the above query is giving both

```
102
103
```

whereas answer should be only 103

Comment: The answer given to you is correct with the condition you have written in `where` clause, because `102` is repeated in your table

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT Case_Id 
FROM Case_transaction_detail
GROUP BY Case_Id 
HAVING SUM(Status = 'Reject') > 0
   and SUM(status = 'Reverify') = 0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT Case_Id 
FROM Case_transaction_detail  
GROUP BY Case_Id
HAVING SUM(Status = 'Reject') > 0 AND
       SUM(status = 'Reverify') = 0;
```

MySQL treats boolean conditions as numbers in a number context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So, the first condition counts the number of rejects; the `> 0` says there is at least one.

Similarly, the second condition counts the number of reverifies for each case.  The `= 0` says there are none.

Comment: Thanks Gordon & Lukasz

Comment: for the same dataset I was trying another question

Comment: Question - Top Agent names with who processed more applications?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a simple `LEFT JOIN`.

Basically, you will select from the table all the rejected CaseIds, and you will left join the same table using the CaseIds selecting only their associated reverifieds.

The ones you want will be the ones where the left join relation (the associated reverifieds) is `NULL`.

```
SELECT CaseRejected.Case_Id 
FROM Case_transaction_detail CaseRejected
LEFT JOIN Case_transaction_detail CaseReverified ON (CaseReverified.Case_Id = CaseRejected.Case_Id AND CaseReverified.Status = 'Reverify') 
WHERE CaseRejected.Status = 'Reject'
AND CaseReverified.Case_Id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to test for homogeneity in the `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT Case_Id 
FROM Case_transaction_detail  
GROUP BY Case_Id
HAVING AVG(Status='Rejected')=1
```

Another method is basically a hack using `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT Case_Id 
FROM Case_transaction_detail  
GROUP BY Case_Id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Status))='Rejected'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Case_Id

FROM case_transaction_details

GROUP BY Case_Id

HAVING SUM(Status = 'Reject') - SUM(status = 'Reverify') = 1
```

Comment: check case for your column `Status` make "S" capital in `SUM(status = 'Reverify')`. Try using `where` clause with `and` condition for the same.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT 
    case_id
FROM
    case_transaction_details
WHERE
    status = 'Reject'
        AND status <> 'Reverify';
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Is there any reason to add this condition twice? As far as I see, the result would be exactly the same when the second one is removed